# jQuery fuction not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to run a simple jQuery function in wordpress to hide and show content depending on a drop-down list, the code works fine outside wordpress, but when I add it to my child theme display all the content. I've checked the header and the jQuery file is loaded properly.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_BJ').closest('article').addClass('city_table').hide();
    $('#id_SH').closest('article').addClass('city_table').hide();
    $('#id_SZ').closest('article').addClass('city_table').hide();

    $('#id_chinese_city').change(function() {
        $('article.city_table').hide();
        $('#id_' + $(this).val()).closest('article').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="chinese_city" id="id_chinese_city">
<option value="">Choose first</option>
<option value="BJ">Beijing</option>
<option value="SH">Shanghai</option>
<option value="SZ">Shenzhen</option>
</select>
<article id="id_BJ">
    </br>
    <h3>Beijing</h3></article>
<article id="id_SH">
    </br>
    <h3>Shanghai</h3></article>
<article id="id_SZ">
    </br>
    <h3>Shenzhen</h3></article>
```

I've also tried to using  tags but the result is the same

any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is the function in a separate js file? Make sure it is loaded after jQuery is defined. Do you have a link for the live page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because you are using the $ with jquery in safe mode, what you can do it change your function like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#id_BJ').closest('article').addClass('city_table').hide();
    $('#id_SH').closest('article').addClass('city_table').hide();
    $('#id_SZ').closest('article').addClass('city_table').hide();

    $('#id_chinese_city').change(function() {
        $('article.city_table').hide();
        $('#id_' + $(this).val()).closest('article').show();
    });
});
```

and it should allow you to pass the $ and it should make your function work.

Look at my document.ready line vs yours to see what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Wordpress runs jQuery in Safe Mode by default.
Change the above line and you should be able to use `$` within your code as normal.

Another alternative is as follows:

```
(function($) {
    //Code here
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thanks I changed all $ for jQuery and now is working.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses jQuery in noConflict mode.

Above solutions should work.

However if you take a look on the APPI Doc this should make it more clear - 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/